# I want to remove index.html from url

Tags: .htaccess

I have setting up htaccess of my laravel website. I have redirected almost urls. But When I trying to remove index.html from url, it is not working. What can I do for remove index.html from url?

I want to remove index.html from url https://www.example.com/index.html. Right now it gives 404 page not found

I have tried simple redirect but it gives to many redirects,Redirect 301 /index.html https://www.example.com/

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Second try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Third try

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is there anyone to reply?

Comment: Instead of using a complex rewriting rule take a look at the ``DirectoryIndex`` directory apache provides.

Comment: @arkascha could you please be a bit specific about how  `DirectoryIndex` can solve the OP's issue :) ?